# Nextjs 13 + Redux toolkit: Sync States between Server and Client side

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, redux-toolkit

When we use redux toolkit + Nextjs 13, do we need to sync the state between next server and client side?

Example:

User Page:
Consider having a flag **isRedirect: false** in next server state and the same flag has been changed to **isRedirect: true** from Client side due to some actions

From Server side
isRedirect: false

After Client action
isRedirect: true

And When I redirect to Home Page from User Page

Home Page:
isRedirect: false

The state is lost and isRedirect will be still false because the state is from next server side. How to overcome this?

Is this even valid to sync states from Client to Server?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you don't - solutions like next-redux-wrapper will only transport Redux state from the server to the client, not the other way round. There is no real mechanism in place for this.

You can transport single values by using a cookie shared between client and server, but these have pretty significant size limitations, so you wouldn't use that to sync a full Redux store.

Comment: This is nice. So we treat two states (Client and server) differently then.

Comment: Yes. The server is not about 100% replicating everything you have on the client - just about giving your client a "kick start".